# Changing Type on ConvertFrom-CSV object

Tags: powershell, csv

I am stuck on something, and I cannot figure out what the issue is.  I have a command that generates CSV formatted text for output.  I have successfully converted the CSV output to a Powershell Object by using ConvertFrom-CSV.  Everything works great!  I wanted to apply some custom formatting, so I wanted to convert the object to a custom pstype name.  I cannot get it to change the type.  ConvertFrom-CSV outputs a PSCustomObject, so I figured it would be easy, but so far no luck.

My Code:

```
##This would be a function "get-devices" that creates command text and outputs the CSV output
##This all works properly
function get-devices {
     $Command.Invoke() | ConvertFrom-Csv
}
$GAMOBJ = get-devices
$GAMOBJ.PSObject.TypeNames.Insert(0,"System.Gam.Device")
$GAMOBJ
```

The object prints properly, but still as a `PSCustomObject`, thus the formatting is not applying.  What am I missing?

Any help is appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Here is the output from Get-Member:

```
       TypeName: Selected.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

    Name        MemberType   Definition                                   
    ----        ----------   ----------                                   
    Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)               
    GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()                            
    GetType     Method       type GetType()                               
    ToString    Method       string ToString()                            
    AssetID     NoteProperty System.String AssetID=ASSETID            
    Expiration  NoteProperty System.String Expiration=2000-01-01          
    Location    NoteProperty System.String Location=LOCATION          
    Model       NoteProperty System.String Model=CHROMEBOOKMODEL
    OU          NoteProperty System.String OU=/                           
    Serial      NoteProperty System.String Serial=123456                 
    Status      NoteProperty System.String Status=ACTIVE
```

Someone added below that I had filtered the object with Select-Object. I removed the select object, and the member type is unchanged.

```
    TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
```

Comment: It "prints properly" but "the formatting is not applying" - sounds like contradicting statements - can you show the output you're getting vs. the output you're expecting? Output from `$GAMOBJ |Get-Member` might be useful here as well

Comment: It prints properly in that the Object is created from the CSV output, but the Object Type has not changed, so my custom table is not applying.

Comment: Here is the output from Get-Member

TypeName: Selected.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Comment: Modifying the type name won't change the type, but it _will_ affect the formatting system. (please [edit your original post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60376874/edit) with the `Get-Member` output and the output printed). Also, double-check whether any custom formatting data for `System.Gam.Device` is actually present with `Get-FormatData -TypeName 'System.Gam.Device'`

Comment: Done.  I have used $var.PSObject.TypeName.Insert(0, 'TypeName') to change typenames of PSCustomObject I have created and it works great, but I cannot get this one to take.  No errors are produced, it just doesn't change the typename.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must insert your ETS type name into *each object's* `.PSTypeNames` collection (aka `.psobject.TypeNames`):

```
$GAMOBJ.ForEach({ $_.PSTypeNames.Insert(0, "System.Gam.Device") })
```

Otherwise, you're only applying the type name to the *array as a whole*, which isn't relevant for printing the objects *one by one*.

Answer (score 1):

You've piped `$GAMOBJ` to `Select-Object` at some point after setting your custom type name (notice the type name displayed by `Get-Member` is `Selected.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject`)

`Select-Object` creates a new object for you, which is why the custom type name you've inserted doesn't persists.

Comment: I did that before I changed the typename.  I used select-object because of how many properties are in the object.  I have updated my post to include the typename from Get-Member without using the Select-Object.

Comment: Please ensure your sample code actually reproduces the issue (copy-paste it into a new instance of `powershell.exe` for example) - there's _no way_ `Get-Member` shows you that type name without the object having been produced by `Select-Object`

Comment: I had commented it out. I apologize, I must have missed something.  I totally removed it, but the output is a system.management.automation.pscustomobject.